# Trouble setting up a developer account and understanding how the sandbox environment works

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

we're not using the API - we just need to integrate a pre-made plugin for our CMS and help our client setup their account.

We've been looking here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

But are having trouble understanding a few things:

1. If you live outside the US, you can't create a developer account on: https://developer.paypal.com
2. Do we somehow create a developer account (and dummy sandbox accounts) on paypal.co.nz?
3. Once we have a developer account, can it granted developer access to the client's PayPal account so we can login and test/trouble shoot any integration issues?

Sorry if this is easy, but we're having trouble finding a good overview or step-by-step of the process.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the sign up form on developer.paypay.com won't accept non-us addresses, you have to sign up by doing the following:

- Go to your local paypal site e.g. paypal.com.au or paypal.co.nz
- Sign up for a normal account
- Go to developer.paypal.com
- Sign in with the normal account you just created

Paypal will then use your new normal account details to create a developer account.

From then on, just login at developer.paypal.com.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Ebay and PayPal have different APIs and different accounts. So creating an account on Ebay would only let you test against the Ebay API.

Can't comment on the NZ vs US thing. The signup form didn't ask me for a country. But, in theory, the developer site shouldn't care (it's a developer site, not live PayPal).

Granting third party access isn't something you do through the Developer site. That's done with your live PayPal credentials and their authorizing you. Not sure if this can be done in REST but it is [possible in Classic](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/)

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply - the ebay thing was an error sorry. The signup form doesn't accept my NZ postal code and I couldn't see a developer signup on the NZ site. Re access to the client account, do they add me as a developer from within their account or can I make a request via my account (as per google ads/analytics)? Cheers

Comment: What you do is you need a live PayPal account with an assigned API authentication set. This consists of a username, password and signature. Then you will provide your username to your clients and they authorize you inside their PayPal account (this is outlined in the link)